# Cells text trails with zeros after copied from another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing this strange problem while copying some rows from workbook-1 sheet-1 to workbook-2 sheet-1 using VBA, the pasted cell's data trails with multiple zeros (only a particular column's data). I have checked the format of the cells, its "General". the option "increase Decimal" or " decrease Decimal" doesn't work cause these are text and I think the number of zero increases as the file grows. 
For example,

WB-1 SH-1, cell value = SB-17.0-AL 
 
WB-2 SH-1, cell value = SB-17.0-AL00000 
after pasting in WB-2 SH-1 from WB-1
WB-2 SH-1, cell value = SB-17.0-AL00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
 after a few days...

```
Sub update_pi()
'IF FILTER IS APPLIED THEN REMOVE IT from slave
If Sheets("slave_PI").FilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter

Dim dop_book As Workbook
Dim dop_sheet As Worksheet

Set dop_book = ThisWorkbook
Set dop_sheet = dop_book.Sheets("slave_PI")

Dim lr_s As Long
lr_s = Sheets("slave_PI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row of slave file

Workbooks.Open "T:\#test_projects\RECORD\PI.xlsm"
    'IF FILTER IS APPLIED THEN REMOVE IT from master
    If Sheets("Sheet1").FilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter
    Dim lr_m As Long
    lr_m = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' last row of master file
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    ' want to copy only newly added rows, as both files has the same no. of rows.
    For y = lr_s To lr_m
        'copy all
        With dop_book.Sheets("slave_PI")
        .Cells(y + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 1).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 2).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 3).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 4).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 6).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 5).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 7).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 13).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 7).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 10).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 8).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 11).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 9).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 16).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 17).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 11).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 21).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 20).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 23).Text
        .Cells(y + 1, 34).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 5).Text ' BUYER
        .Cells(y + 1, 35).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 22).Text ' STYLE
        .Cells(y + 1, 36).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 3).Text ' PI NO.
        .Cells(y + 1, 28).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 9).Text ' ITEM CODE
        End With
    Next y

Workbooks("PI.xlsm").Close SAVECHANGES:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what exactly is causing the problem, but I'd recommend changing `.Text` to `.Value`.

Comment: Is this all the relevant code? Do these zeros get there after a few days by themselves or actually after running the macro more than once? Sidenote: You have 10 currently open question. Even from back in 2016. You should revisit them and see which ones you can close as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) explanation in the tour.

Comment: @JvdV as I have mentioned, I don't know what causes this, if running the macro multiple time or on the air. <br> here is the data flow structure...
`WB-1 Sh-1 (typed) >> it sends data to WB-2 Sh-1 (master file)
 WB-3 Sh-1 (retrieves data from WB-2 Sh-1 using macro) >> Wb-3 Sh-1 sends these data to WB-4 Sh-1(second master file) >>
WB-5 Sh-1 retrieves the newly added data rows from Wb-4 Sh-1 every day using a macro and here in the Wb-5 Sh-1 problem arises
`
I have added the complete module please take a look.
working on your side note, thanks.